# Upgrading the SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

My SQL Server version at home is 661 and at my school's is 655, so every time I try to open my web's SQL Server database at school it says there is an error:

[image]

So I thought that uploading the SQL Server version at school will fix it (or downgrading the SQL Server version in my home).

On both computers there is **Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010**

How do I upgrade the SQL Server version?

Comment: go to Microsoft downloads and download a newer version?

Comment: the newset version there is the 655, like in my school. i dont know how it is possible

Comment: You likely need a service pack or a cumulative update.  Both are available from the Microsoft download site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a compatibility level will help you. You can define it in the options of your database under compatibility level. Change it to a version earlier of your current sql server at home. This way I'm sure it will be correctly used in your school.